# query two datatables in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I am stuck with an issue.
I have two datatables, with the same table structure, i need to select data from table1 such that the records arent existing in table2
is it possible to do this in vb.net? if yes then how?

```
Table1(AAno,Agencyname,location)
Table2(AAno,Agencyname,location)
```

Criteria:`Select AAno,Agencyname,location from table1,table2 where table1.AAno<>table2.AAno`

Comment: Could you give us the structure of your datatables, and the criters you are going to use ?

Comment: @squelos plz check the question updated above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `LINQ-to-DataSet` and [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx#Y210) to find the rows in table1 that are not in table2. Assuming that `AAno` is the primary key:

```
Dim t1AAno = table1.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("AAno"))
Dim t2AAno = table2.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(r) r.Field(Of Int32)("AAno"))
Dim uniqueAAno = t1AAno.Except(t2AAno).ToList()
Dim tblResult = (From row In table1.AsEnumerable()
                 Join AAno In uniqueAAno
                 On row.Field(Of Int32)("AAno") Equals AAno
                 Select row).CopyToDataTable()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim Schmelter.
Actually i had very less time to wait for the reply so i tried something else other then datatable to get my work done.
My application is in .net 2.0, so cant make use of LINQ.But still thanks for the information, it's realy helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ADO.Net in VB.Net.
If you are familar with ADO.Net get data into your `DataTable` Class after passing your query in

```
SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand("Select AAno,Agencyname,location from table1,table2 where table1.AAno<>table2.AAno",conn);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt); //dt is a datatable
```

Comment: In the sql command above i hope you are referring table1 and table2 as datatables(VB.net) and not sql tables.
Will implement the above and let you know the result.
Thanks